# Object.wait(0) and Condition.await() fail to return?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized, infinite

Years ago, after spending days trying to figure out a deadlock problem, I was told that (due to bugs in the JVM and/or OS) there were scenarios where Object.wait(0) could fail to return when it should and that I should never use an infinite blocking call on a monitor or lock. Adding a non-zero argument worked and I've used this pattern in all my code since.

For example, code that looks something like this:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    while (monitor_condition) {
        monitor.wait(0L);
    }
}
// or
lock.lock();
try {
    while (lock_condition) {
        condition.await();
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

I instead write like this (and have for decades):

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    while (monitor_condition) {
        monitor.wait(1000L);
    }
}
// or
lock.lock();
try {
    while (lock_condition) {
        condition.await(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

I was recently asked during a code review why I wrote my code like this and (after relating my war story) I decided to poke around on the Internet looking for current literature or work stories as to whether or not others continue to have similar deadlocking problems with the infinite blocking versions of *wait* and *await*. I turned up nothing.

As there is nothing technically incorrect with either of the above code blocks (my preferred approach simply using a few more CPU cycles than necessary) this question is more of a collective request for comments. I'll post my question here regardless for it is programming related.

Anyway, I was wondering whether anyone out there has experienced a so-called *spurious deadlock* (as compared to the *spurious wakeup* in the Java 1.[78] java documentation) using modern JVMs (e.g., 1.7+) where a monitor was notified or a condition signaled and the blocked thread **failed** to return from the infinite *wait* or *await* call?

i.e., given code to unblock the above example something along these lines:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    monitor_condition = false;
    monitor.notifyAll();
}
// or
lock.lock();
try {
    lock_condition = false;
    condition.signalAll();
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

has anyone observed behavior where, at code completion of the unblocking code, the *wait* or *await* methods from the first example above fail to return (stuck, as it were, in an infinite wait)?

Comment: In particular, I'm NOT looking for errors due to code, but, given correct code the blocking API failed to return. This may be a Future.get(), Object.wait, Condition.await() or any of the myriad high level constructs that fail to return due to problems in the underlying implementation.

Comment: I've never heard of it or seen such code.

Comment: A link or reference to anything in the technical literature, article, blog post, or even documentation in legacy open source code would be ideal. Personal war stories, of course, would also be appreciated.